# Precision function/operator in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can anyone tell how to get precision of 2 digits after decimal number in python arithmetic.I want float number to be printed with 2 digits after decimal.
I have used round() function but still not getting correct output.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is something like the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module what you're looking for?

Comment: Printing is one thing, arithmetic another.  Please edit your Q to give a small example of what you've tried, what result you expect, what you get instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
num = 3.1415
print '%.2f' % num # prints 3.14
```

The `f` is a floating point number place holder. `.2` indicates 2 decimal places when formatting `num`.

**Edit:** What is wrong with round?

```
print round(3.1415, 2) # 2 is decimal places
```